# I dont know how to pass two queryset parameters into one URL

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I really struggled to explain my problem and the only way I found it would be possible is - through screenshots as I have a lot of code and I am not sure what is really needed here. So if you want any code, tell me I will add.

The numbers on the pictures indicate the order.

[Choosing the category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0kKB.png)
Selecting the category it redirects me to - /products_list?category=**(that category_id)**

[Filtering through brand in that category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOL1.png)
Now please pay attention to the **URL** and what happens after I have chosen the brand I want to filter with.

[Back on the first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1ptU.png)
**Problem is here:**
Now I am back on the first page, where are **all** the products but I wanted it to stay on that URL where are that kind of category products.

**What I wanted to happen?** Instead of it taking me to the page where are **ALL** the products and then doing the filtering, I want it to stay on that category page and return the filtered products there.

The brand dropdown menu also should only show that category products that I am in, not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the other parameters as well. So that means that for two parameters `category_id` and `brand`, you create a URL that looks like:

```
{% url 'product-list' %}?category={{ category_id|urlencode }}&brand={{ brand|urlencode }}
```

If you thus already filtered the category down, you pass the `category_id` to the template, and render the URLs with the `?category={{ category_id|urlencode }}` part.

Comment: I literally did it and all I missed was a single ' & '. Still Thank You so much!! I was so worried...